# Clojure CLI clear screen

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

Pardon me but I've just started learning clojure. I've run many commands in REPL CLI. But now I'm not able to clear the CLI screen. cls command also doesn't work inside the REPL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run the repl in your terminal, try to find `clear buffer` command in the terminal app and key binding for the command.

Comment: @ntalbs cls command can be used to clear screen outside the repl, but i can't find `clear buffer` command which can be used within repl..

Comment: Does `(clojure.java.shell/sh "cls")` work?

Comment: @coredump No it isn't working..

Comment: Hit enter a bunch of times until you get visual separation between what you were doing before and what you want to do next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try pressing `Control-l` (lower case 'L' - not the number one). If the that doesn't work try starting the REPL using rlwrap, which may implement the readline support for clearing the screen. But this all depends on how you are starting the repl, and on what platform. There's no global way to clear a terminal across Windows and UNIX variants and other containers such as Emacs buffers and Atom/ProtoREPL. This isn't really something the REPL can reasonably support since the buffer is not held by the Clojure/JVM process, but by the container you're using to display it to your screen. It's also likely that your terminal emulator provides a way to clear the buffer.